# A valid reason to enable CDATA support for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, cdata, plc

I am posing this use case as a reason to enable support for the CDATA section of XML documents on SQL Server, in response to the opinion of [Michael Rys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318169/michael-rys).

He states that 
"[There is no semantic difference in the data that you store.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e22efff3-192e-468e-b173-ced52ada857f/how-to-get-cdata-with-for-xml-path?forum=sqlxml)"

I am a software controls engineer where we use a supervised distributed system, we generally have a windows based server and database for supervisory functions as well as high speed machine control applications. We use any number of PLCs to compose our distributed control system, and we keep a copy of the PLC program on the server. The PLC program is [L5X format that calls for the CDATA section per specification (see page 40 for more info)](http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/rm/1756-rm084_-en-p.pdf).

The CDATA section is used for component descriptions due to invalid XML characters being present in some of them and the need to preserve them:

"*Component descriptions are brought into the project without being processed by
the XML parser for markup language. **The description text is contained in a
CDATA element, a standard in the XML specification.** A CDATA element
begins with the character sequence `<![CDATA[` and ends with the character
sequence `]]>`. None of the text within the CDATA element is interpreted by the
XML parser. The CDATA element preserves formatting so there is no need to use
control characters to enter formatted descriptions.*"

Here, I think at least, is an entirely valid reason for the existence and use of the CDATA section - in contrast the the opinion of Microsoft.

Comment: This site is for programming questions and answers. I don't see a question here at all, only an argument for supporting CDATA in XML.

Comment: Is there a programming question here or are you just soliciting opinions? Incidentally, if you *must* support `CDATA` as-is, consider just using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` rather than `XML`. The dedicated type is nice, but by no means essential.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question.

Comment: Could you use an XSLT transform with output-cdata-section-elements if you really need it (though I still don't see why, except to make it more easily human-readable.

Comment: The point of the the post is to asses whether or not this is a suitable reason to support CDATA on SQL Server. The question is in the title, sorry it's not so black and white for you guys.

Comment: @Joe, we need is for various reasons. But primarily because the PLC engineers put stuff in there that they need. Stuff to be displayed on screen, read by a maintainer, etc. And we use the program to pull variable names, register positions, etc.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based then. Alas, I already voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", but imagine I used that as a close reason instead. What is or is not a "valid" reason would depend entirely on who you ask, I think. You'd probably answer "yes". The Microsoft engineers who [aren't implementing it](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/298860) would probably answer "no". If you want to change their minds, a question on SO to gauge support isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @two_what: the progam should have no problem pulling values; that's what Michael Rys meant by "no semantically difference".  For allowing editing in a text editor by humans, I suggest using an XSLT transform to generate CDATA sections is more feasible than getting MS to enhance SQL Server.

Comment: From the comments on the answers, it seems clear that you've got an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you don't need something to change in SQL Server, you've got a problem passing encoded XML. If you have specific details (as in code) on how the data gets passed to SQL Server, consider asking a new question with the proper focus.

Answer (score 0):

Buggy tools.

You may find it more or less convenient, but the only technical reasons is if you have buggy tools that don't follow the XML rules in some way.

> The CDATA section is used for component descriptions due to invalid XML characters being present in some of them and the need to preserve them.

Either you mean characters that are invalid in XML unescaped, in which case they could also be escaped, or you mean characters that are not valid in XML at all, in which case they are not valid CDATA sections. In the first case if your tools can't work with that, they are buggy. In the second case if your tools require you to work with that, they are buggy. Either way this is in the buggy tools category.

Comment: Some examples of what I've been seeing as I try to build this are the degree symbol as well as a few dash-dashes. From everything I'm seeing this is the point of CDATA, to put non-xml stuff in it that will not be parsed. I could ask the PLC guys to only use valid XML characters, but the L5X spec expects to have these things allowed.

Comment: The degree symbol is a valid XML character, as are every dash- and hyphen-like character in the UCS.

Comment: Well all I had to go on was the SQL Server was complaining saying that they weren't and wouldn't let me copy the xml into the DB until I removed those characters, as well as single quotes in the CDATA section too.

Comment: Something else is wrong. `<range>20–35°</range>` is perfectly valid XML.

Comment: I just tried setting this string `<![CDATA[M22325 ARSP MERGE NORTH L4.1 2:1 MRG EXIT V-BELT 90° CURVE]]>` as the text and got an "illegal xml character" error.

Comment: Well, that proves it; if it doesn't work with cdata sections either, that's clearly not the solution. What encoding is the XML being stored in?

Comment: UTF8 I believe, I just read something about that character being above 127 so that could be the issue

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<![CDATA[M22325 ARSP MERGE NORTH L4.1 2:1 MRG EXIT V-BELT 90° CURVE]]>')` works fine (and without `CDATA` as well). It's not SQL Server that has trouble storing specific characters, it's how the data gets sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus in the XML community is that the following three forms are semantically equivalent:

```
<x>±</x>

<x>&#177;</x>

<x><![CDATA[±]]></x>
```

and that XML processing software therefore does not need to preserve the distinction between them. This is why entity references (or numeric character references) and CDATA sections are not part of the data model used by XPath, XSLT, and XQuery (known as XDM).

Unfortunately the XML specification itself does not define a data model and is rather weak on saying which constructs are information-bearing and which are not, so there will always be people coming up with arguments like this, just as there will be people arguing that the order of attributes should be preserved.

Comment: My problem is specifically with SQL Server, because our PLC guys put single quotes and other things in the CDATA section that need to be displayed as they've typed. SQL Server thinks these single quotes matter when they in fact should not. It's just character data that should not be parsed.